# How can I ensure two tasks are running on different threads or even different processors with the new Task Parallel Library?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, network-programming, task-parallel-library

I have two long running tasks that read and write simultaneously from a network stream which requires me to use two different threads.
I have marked them as long running but according to the docs marking them as long running only recommends but doesn't guarantee that they will run on different threads.
Do I need to write my own Task Scheduler? Should I use the thread pool instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "network stream" means the `NetworkStream` class, I'm not sure why you really need two separate threads here. Are you basing that on the following quote from the documentation:

> "As long as there is one unique thread for the write operations and one unique thread for the read operations, there will be no cross-interference between read and write threads and no synchronization is required"

If so, that's only a suggestion - they're saying that if you do things this way, you don't need to do any synchronization. The main reason they're saying this is that `NetworkStream` is unusual in that it supports access from two threads simultaneously as long as one is reading and one is writing.

But it's clear from the documentation that you also have the option to perform synchronization - they're just saying that synchronization is unnecessary if you choose to go down the path of having exactly one read thread, and exactly one write thread.

But if for some reason you really do need two dedicated threads, then...I'd just use the `Thread` class. Trying to get `Task` to do that for you (either directly, or indirectly via a `TaskScheduler`) is probably just making things more complex. This doesn't prevent you from using the TPL - you could use the `TaskCompletionSource` to create tasks, and finish them at your own leisure. (TCS is the normal solution for situations where you want to control how tasks execute, but still expose them as a `Task` object.)

Comment: I need to both read and write at the same time because I am streaming. So if I am getting it right I should use the tasks only for executing tasks inside the thread, right?

Comment: I wasn't questioning whether you need to read and write simultaneously. I was questioning the need for (specifically) two threads. You might have any number of threads - as long as no more than 1 reads at any one time and no more than 1 writes at any one time, you don't need to dedicate one thread to reading and one thread to writing. There are a couple of reasons to use Task: a) use a built-in Task if its execution model suits you - not the case here - or b) implement your own Task if you have an unusual execution model, but still want Task semantics. b) might suit you here, perhaps.

Answer (score 4):

LongRunning is a hint that it should be executed on a new Thread, instead of an existing thread in the ThreadPool. This is so you wont exhaust the ThreadPool with long-running tasks.

There are no guarantees that two different threads will be used, neither in TPL, nor with the ThreadPool. For example, it could be the same thread executing both tasks synchronously.

Have you looked into using asynchronous io instead?

Comment: Do you mean using BeginXXX and EndXX yes but that also can complete synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] forums = File.ReadAllLines(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\forums.txt");

Task[] tasks = new Task[forums.Length ];
int ctr = 0;
DateTime Start = DateTime.Now;`
foreach(string s in forums)`
{
object state = s;
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomeWork(state),TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
tasks[ctr] = task;
ctr++;
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan elapsed = end - Start;
string totalMs = elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString();
Console.WriteLine("DONE in " +totalMs + " ms. Any Key to quit.");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

The LongRunning enum method overload tells the Task library to dedicate a thread to each task, regardless of the number of cores it can use.

Comment: I know that, but it's just a suggestion. Isn't it>